# Mysql - Discrepancy failing to load Query Result

Tags: mysql

I am experiencing a strange event when retrieving the result of my query in the staging environment against using my localhost

So I am connecting 8 tables , for making it simple the query goes like this:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
tsales, stores, vma_users, tracks, albums, fa_country, exchange_rates, outlets
WHERE tsales.type = 'T' 
AND stores.outlet_id = exchange_rates.outlet_id
AND stores.outlet_id = outlets.id
AND tsales.store_id = exchange_rates.outlet_id
AND tsales.sale_year = exchange_rates.year
AND tsales.sale_month = exchange_rates.month
AND tsales.currency = exchange_rates.currency
AND tsales.track_id = tracks.id
AND tracks.album_id = albums.id
AND tsales.country = fa_country.iso
AND tsales.account_id = vma_users.id
AND tsales.account_id = 2129
AND tsales.sale_year = 2013
AND tsales.sale_month = 3
ORDER BY tsales.id
```

(Don't worry about the query, I also have a left join version of this )

Whenever I run this query in the staging environment , I can retrieve a result like for example 26k rows meanwhile whenever I run this in my localhost in sql phpmyadmin seems nothing happening and I can't even get a result later it will display something like this

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.4.10.1\libraries\session.inc.php on line 92
```

The data and structure of my localhost and staging are the same. I just updated it.

Can you help me please what's going on. I do know this happens for big records but I am expecting only 26k rows so it wouldn't matter.

Running the query with EXPLAIN :

```
1   SIMPLE  outlets     ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    46  Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  stores  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    55  Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  fa_country  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    213     Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  exchange_rates  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1390    Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  vma_users   ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    3957    Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  albums  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    78458   Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  tsales  ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    893483  Using where; Using join buffer
1   SIMPLE  tracks  eq_ref  PRIMARY,album_id    PRIMARY     4   valleyarm_digital.tsales.track_id   1   Using where
```

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN <your query>` on your local host and post results here in a textual form

Comment: @peterm updated it please see above the result using EXPLAIN

Comment: You just don't have indices on columns which you use to join and filter your tables thus end up with full scans. And in your staging environment you have them.

Comment: @peterm, I see makes sense, question whenever I export the records to .sql from staging and import it in my localhost would it get also the settings for indices?

Comment: @DrixsonOseña no, you have to recreate whole schema.

Comment: add index to all columns in where but i think there is some problem with design also

Comment: @kworr thanks! I will take note of it.

Comment: @ArunKillu There's a big problem with design. Actually it should be carefully planned when and what to add to indexes as big number of indexes tends to slow down `INSERT`s.

Comment: @kworr yes it will be a a problem may be schema change is better

Comment: @DrixsonOseña It depends on how you export data. It can be done in several ways.

Comment: No worries, only tracks and albums tables have only insert process , rest are predefined and data are uploaded. Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own problem with the guides of professional here.

The discrepancy in getting the query result against the staging development and localhost happens because it loses the indices when sql file are imported in localhost first impression is that it will also copy the indices but you need to recreate the whole schema from staging to localhost.

As explained in [Mysql Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) MySQL can quickly determine the position to seek to in the middle of the data file without having to look at all the data.

So without using indices it ends up a full scan which leads on failing to retrieve the result.